# <td>s not stacking properly in responsive email

Tags: html-email, responsive-emails

So I'm trying to build my first responsive email, and everything is going pretty well except for my two navigation areas. The first one, I have four buttons that I would like to rearrange from running across, to stacking two ontop of two. It worked in my initial testing, but then when I sent it through my email provider, the first two tds rendered properly (both 50%) but the two that were supposed to lay underneath were all squished up to the side. Same for the second navigation I was trying to do (except, I wanted the three to switch to 100% on top of each other)

Any suggestions on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated! Here is my code (which, is working fine here, but breaks in on all mobile when I actually send it out):

```css
/* Stacked Top Links Navigation Pattern CSS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    td[class="main_nav"] {
        padding: 0;
    }
    td[class="main_nav"] td {
        display: inline-block;
        /*float: left;*/
        padding: 0 !important;
        width: 50%;
    }
    td[class="main_nav"] a {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 0;
        background: #565656;
    }
    td[class="main_nav"] .nav1 a,
    td[class="main_nav"] .nav2 a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
    }
    td[class="main_nav"] .nav1 a,
    td[class="main_nav"] .nav3 a {
        border-right: 1px solid #777;
    }
}

/* Stacked Top Links Navigation Pattern CSS */
@media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    td[class="secondary_nav"] {
        padding: 0;
    }
    td[class="secondary_nav"] td {
        display: inline-block;
        /*float: left;*/
        padding: 0 !important;
        width: 100%;
    }
    td[class="secondary_nav"] a {
        display: block;
        padding: 10px 0;
        background: #005c5b;
        text-align: center;
    }
    td[class="secondary_nav"] .nav1 a,
    td[class="secondary_nav"] .nav2 a {
        border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
    }
}
```

```html
 <!-- BEGINNING OF NAVIGATION -->
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#565656">
      <tr>
          <td class="main_nav" width="600" bgcolor="#565656">
              <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#565656" style="width:100%!important">
                  <tr>
                      <td class="nav1" align="center" style="padding: 10px 10px; font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">
                          <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;">Nav 1</a>
                      </td>
                      <td class="nav2" align="center" style="padding: 10px 10px; font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">
                       <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;">Nav 2</a>
                      </td>
                      <td class="nav3" align="center" style="padding: 10px 10px; font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">
                       <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;">Nav 3</a>
                      </td>
                      <td align="center" style="padding: 10px 10px; font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">
                       <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;">Nav 4</a>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <br/>
  <!-- END OF NAVIGATION -->

<!-- BEGINNING OF SECONDARY STORY NAVIGATION -->
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td class="secondary_nav" width="600">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#005c5b">
                <tr>
                    <td class="nav1" width="33.33%" align="center" style="padding: 20px 10px 20px 30px; text-align:left;border-right:solid 1px #ffffff;">
                        <a href="bottom-section" style="font-family:arial; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none;">Secondary nav 1</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="nav2" width="33.33%" align="center" style="padding: 20px 10px 20px 30px; font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px; text-align:left;border-right:solid 1px #ffffff;">
                        <a href="bottom-section" style="font-family:arial; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;">Secondary nav 2</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="nav3" width="33.33%" align="center" style="padding: 20px 10px 20px 30px; font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px; text-align:left;">
                        <a href="bottom-section" style="font-family:arial; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;">Secondary nav 3</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<!-- END OF SECONDARY STORY NAVIGATION -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest swapping out your inline cells for aligned tables. Cells won't play nice with 50%, you always need to go just under that. In saying that, your cells will never align correctly, which you'll see in my version below.

One draw back to using aligned tables so close is that you'll need to add in ghost tables around your tables, to ensure Outlook respects the close alignment you want and doesn't add the 20px margin it requires between tables.

I only made a tweak to your original cell width, to 49% in the header CSS and then I created my aligned tables version in a new row underneath your original code, with a new main_nav_inner class inside of my wrapping table.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
    
 <style type="text/css">
  /* Stacked Top Links Navigation Pattern CSS */
  @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
   td[class="main_nav"] {
    padding: 0;
   }
   td[class="main_nav"] td {
    display: inline-block;
    /*float: left;*/
    padding: 0 !important;
    width: 49%;
   }
   td[class="main_nav2"] .main_nav_inner table {
    width: 50%!important;
   }
   td[class="main_nav"] a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: #565656;
   }
   td[class="main_nav"] .nav1 a,
   td[class="main_nav"] .nav2 a,
   td[class="main_nav2"] .main_nav_inner .nav1,
   td[class="main_nav2"] .main_nav_inner .nav2  {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
   }
   td[class="main_nav"] .nav1 a,
   td[class="main_nav"] .nav3 a,
   td[class="main_nav2"] .main_nav_inner .nav1,
   td[class="main_nav2"] .main_nav_inner .nav3 {
    border-right: 1px solid #777;
   }
  }
  
  /* Stacked Top Links Navigation Pattern CSS */
  @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
   td[class="secondary_nav"] {
    padding: 0;
   }
   td[class="secondary_nav"] td {
    display: inline-block;
    /*float: left;*/
    padding: 0 !important;
    width: 100%;
   }
   td[class="secondary_nav"] a {
    display: block;
    padding: 10px 0;
    background: #005c5b;
    text-align: center;
   }
   td[class="secondary_nav"] .nav1 a,
   td[class="secondary_nav"] .nav2 a {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #fff;
   }
  }
 </style>
</head>
<body style="min-width: 100%; padding-bottom: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-left: 0px; margin: 0px; padding-right: 0px" yahoo="fix">
<!-- BEGINNING OF NAVIGATION -->
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" bgcolor="#565656" width="100%">
      <tr>
          <td class="main_nav" bgcolor="#565656">
              <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#565656" style="width:100%!important">
                  <tr>
                      <td class="nav1" align="center" style="padding: 10px 10px; font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">
                          <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;">Nav 1</a>
                      </td>
                      <td class="nav2" align="center" style="padding: 10px 10px; font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">
                       <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;">Nav 2</a>
                      </td>
                      <td class="nav3" align="center" style="padding: 10px 10px; font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">
                       <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;">Nav 3</a>
                      </td>
                      <td class="nav4" align="center" style="padding: 10px 10px; font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">
                       <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;">Nav 4</a>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
          </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
          <td class="main_nav2" bgcolor="#565656">
              <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#565656" style="width:100%!important">
                  <tr>
                   <td class="main_nav_inner">
                         <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:600px;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td valign="top" style="width:150px;">
                        <![endif]-->
                     <table align="left" class="nav1" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:25%;">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" style="padding: 10px 10px; font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">
                                      <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;">Nav 1</a>
                                  </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                    </td>
                                    <td valign="top" style="width:150px;">
                        <![endif]-->
                     <table align="left" class="nav2" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:25%;">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" style="padding: 10px 10px; font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">
                                   <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;">Nav 2</a>
                                  </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                    </td>
                                    <td valign="top" style="width:150px;">
                        <![endif]-->
                     <table align="left" class="nav3" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:25%;">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" style="padding: 10px 10px; font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">
                                   <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;">Nav 3</a>
                                  </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                    </td>
                                    <td valign="top" style="width:150px;">
                        <![endif]-->
                     <table align="left" class="nav4" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:25%;">
                            <tr>
                                <td align="center" style="padding: 10px 10px; font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px;">
                                   <a href="#" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;">Nav 4</a>
                                  </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                        <!--[if gte mso 9]>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table>
                        <![endif]-->
                    </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
          </td>
      </tr>
  </table>
  <br/>
  <!-- END OF NAVIGATION -->

<!-- BEGINNING OF SECONDARY STORY NAVIGATION -->
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:collapse;">
    <tr>
        <td class="secondary_nav" width="600">
            <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%" bgcolor="#005c5b">
                <tr>
                    <td class="nav1" width="33.33%" align="center" style="padding: 20px 10px 20px 30px; text-align:left;border-right:solid 1px #ffffff;">
                        <a href="bottom-section" style="font-family:arial; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;color:#ffffff; text-decoration:none;">Secondary nav 1</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="nav2" width="33.33%" align="center" style="padding: 20px 10px 20px 30px; font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px; text-align:left;border-right:solid 1px #ffffff;">
                        <a href="bottom-section" style="font-family:arial; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;">Secondary nav 2</a>
                    </td>
                    <td class="nav3" width="33.33%" align="center" style="padding: 20px 10px 20px 30px; font-family: arial,sans-serif; font-size: 11px; text-align:left;">
                        <a href="bottom-section" style="font-family:arial; font-weight:bold; font-size:14px;text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff;">Secondary nav 3</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<!-- END OF SECONDARY STORY NAVIGATION -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you!! It looks so perfect on all the iphones! It looks really wonky on Andriod phones and Outlook 2007-16 (but fine in 2003 and 2011). Do you have any suggestions? I don't know if there is a way that I can show you a screenshot?

Comment: In Android, the tables aren't going their full width - so text isn't aligning where it should be, and since there is a background colour it's very evident. (General issue for me, happening everywhere in the email, not just in the navs) Also, not sure if media queries work since the nav tables aren't wrapping underneath each other like they should. In Outlook, it's kinda like the tables just... don't know what size to be, they're all different, and the text is squished.

Comment: By using tables and the "ghost" tables around them to allow the tables to sit so close, you can't get the width right, without setting a width or max-width on the parent table. If you can do that, divide that width by four and set that width on each of the "ghost" tables.

Comment: The Main nav I have added looks perfect on phones, your nav won't because of the use of cells.

Cells cannot be set to full width on Android mail clients any more, they updated their rendering engine, so you'll also have to convert your Secondary nav to tables, using the "ghost" tables to ensure they align side by side as you have it now.

Let me know if you have any trouble. You should be able to reuse my code and just update the styling. Remember to divide the width of 600 you have set, by three and set that width on the "ghost" tables